# Dynamically change image in javascript

Tags: javascript

JavaScript Noob here.

I want to show the dynamically changing image effect like this:
http://dotsignals.org/google_popup.php?cid=202
(if this webpage cannot show changing image, click on any camera at http://dotsignals.org)

I have examined the code, and have some questions:

1.The website uses `setImage` and `refreshSetImage` to initialize and refresh the image for a dynamically changing effect. What is the use of Math.random in here? I understand it is a way to differentiate images from different time at the same cam. But how does it works? How would the backend respond?

2.Related to the first question. What is the mechanism of the refreshSetImage? I didn't see any sign of requesting data from the server. Does it send a "GET"? How does it refresh the image?

```
function setImage(imageID){
    var currentImage = imageID;
    document.getElementById(currentImage).src ='http://207.251.86.238/cctv9.jpg'+'?math=';

    refreshSetImage();
}
function refreshSetImage() {

   document.images["myCam"].src = 'http://207.251.86.238/cctv9.jpg'+'?math='+Math.random();
   setTimeout('refreshSetImage()',1000);
}
function ScaleSize(imageID) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(imageID);
    elem.style.width = 500;
    elem.style.height = 300;
}
```

3.How is the backend designed? 
4.Now I want to use these two functions in my own project. I want to add a parameter of `camID` in the `setImage` and `refreshSetImage` functions, so the `src` of the image will change to something like: `'http://..../'+camID+'.jpg'+'?math'`.  `camID` is a String that identifies different cameras. I changed it to:

```
    function refreshSetImage(camID) {

   document.images["myCam"].src = 'http://207.251.86.238/'+camID+'.jpg'+'?math='+Math.random();
   setTimeout('refreshSetImage(camID)',1000);
}

function setImage(imageID,camID){
    var currentImage = imageID;
  document.getElementById(currentImage).src = 'http://207.251.86.238/'+camID+'.jpg'+'?math=';

    refreshSetImage(camID);
}
```

and got an error :`Uncaught ReferenceError: camID is not defined  VM132:1`. The image is not changing as well. I don't know what is the problem. What is `VM132:1` ?

Thanks

Comment: The Math.Random is the make sure the image you're requesting is not from cache. You add a "unique"-ish key to make sure the browser actually attempts to get a new image.
How is the backend designed : good question... ask the original developers..
If you want to make your own backend.. also ask them: it could be they restricted access to their video loop and that *could* be why you get an error (but this is just a guess(

Comment: http://207.251.86.238/cctv9.jpg?time=1   http://207.251.86.238/cctv9.jpg?time=2    the params time or math if to reload image.. and in your problem, camID is not defined is a error when you not assign value in your variable

Comment: I made it work by periodically requesting data from the back end using JQuery get()

Answer (score -1):

check

```
function refreshSetImage(imageID,camID) {
   currentImage = imageID;
   url = 'http://207.251.86.238/'+camID+'.jpg'+'?math='+Math.random();
   //document.getElementById(currentImage).src= url;
   console.log(url);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

imageID = "imageID";
camID = "camID";

setInterval(function() {
    refreshSetImage("imageID","camID");
}, 3000);


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/vr1ftwg1/

Comment: All you did was copy the original code then apply a `setInterval` instead of a `setTimeout`. That won't change anything.

Comment: setInterval('refreshSetImage('+camID+')', 1000);  add ('+camID+')

Comment: It's still wrong. [They're going to lose the reference to the function.](https://jsfiddle.net/91cy1puf/) Your final option is almost right. If they did `setInterval` using a function reference rather than a string then it would work. It a bad idea to use strings with `setInterval` and `setTimeout` anyway. No reason not to just use a plain old function.

Comment: I am wondering if `"refreshSetImage('"+camID+"')"`would work? Since camID is expected to be a string.